# Data Classes and PEP 8

Tags: python, pep8, dataclasses

Are data classes considered the same as a normal class when it comes to the styling conventions found in PEP8?  In other words, should you use camel case for a data class, etc...

I reviewed both PEP 8 and PEP 557. Neither explicitly mentions styling for data classes. Of course, there's guidance for classes and technically a dataclass is still a class. But I'd like clarification from the community about usual practices.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you would distinguish them. `@dataclass` is just a shortcut for defining the classes, but you use it similarly to an ordinary class.

Comment: In particular, the user of the class doesn't generally need to know that it was defined using @dataclass.